# Laravel : How to retrieve a column of intermediate table as an array?

Tags: laravel

How to retrieve a column of intermediate table as an array?

For example：
The intermediate table of `users` and `roles` ,named `role_user`,it is like this:

```
id
user_id
role_id
```

I want to get current user's `role_id`s:

```
public function test()
{
    //$roles is a collection.
    $roles=Auth::user()->roles;

    //I want to get `role_id`s like this：
    //$roleIds=[1,2,3];
}
```

How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried `Auth::user()->roles()->pluck('id')` ?

Answer (score 1):

use this eloquent relationship function in your **user** model

```
public function roles()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function getUserRole()
{
   return $this->roles()->first();
}
```

if user has one role you can access like this

```
Auth::user()->getUserRole();
```

if user has many roles you can call

```
Auth::user()->roles;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use Collection's `pluck` method. [See the documentation.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck)

```
$roleIds = $roles->pluck('id')
```